# Laravel - Failed asserting that null is an instance of class "App\User"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I am working through Laracast Tutorial: [link](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/3?autoplay=true) . My forum-project works in the browser. I can see all threads with associated replies. These replies contains user information with timestamp.  But phpunit test fails and I can't understand why:

```
λ vendor\bin\phpunit tests\Unit\ReplyTest.php
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 360 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\ReplyTest::it_has_an_owner
Failed asserting that null is an instance of class "App\User".

C:\laragon\www\forum\tests\Unit\ReplyTest.php:19

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Here is my **ReplyTest.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;


class ReplyTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test **/
    public function it_has_an_owner()
    {
        $reply = factory('App\User')->create();

        $this->assertInstanceOf('App\User', $reply->owner);
    }
}
```

My Eloquent Model **Reply.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reply extends Model
{
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Code from **ModelFactory.php**:

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Thread::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'user_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\User')->create()->id;
        },
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'body' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Reply::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'thread_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\Thread')->create()->id;
        },

        'user_id' => function() {
            return factory('App\User')->create()->id;
        },
        'body' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

Code extract from **show.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    @foreach ($thread->replies as $reply)
     <div class="panel-heading">
        <a href="#">
            {{ $reply->owner->name }}
        </a>
        said {{ $reply->created_at->diffForHumans() }} ... 
    </div> 

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{ $reply->body }}
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I hope I posted all relevant code - if not, tell me please what you need and I will post it. I can't figure out why phpunit returns an error while everything works in the browser.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead consider marking an answer as accepted. This will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Comment: @Bugs I can't, because I get an notification "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". Do you know why I have to wait so long?

Comment: There is some meta surrounding this subject. Here are the links; [Why can't you accept your own answer immediately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately) and [Why must I wait 2 days before accepting my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer) should give you the answers you are looking for. It's a bit of a pain but I guess these rules are in place to stop people gaming the system.

Comment: What is the purpose of the test?

Comment: We don't need the view, and the `static` properties `$password` are never used in the closures used for creating fixtures for `App\Thread` and `App\Reply`. Also, you can use the `class` keyword in your tests as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found my error. I used factory for wrong Class and created User instead of Reply. After changing it everything works:

```
$reply = factory('App\Reply')->create();
```